# Can populate method in mongoose return a tree structure data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a model tree structures with parent references, this is my schema file:

```
export class Menu {
...
  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Menu' })
  childrens: Menu[];
}
export const MenuSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Menu);
```

some data in my database:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('menu1'),
    name: 'menu1',
    ...
    childrens: [ObjectId['menu1-1']],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('menu1-1'),
    name: 'menu1-1',
    ...
    childrens: [ObjectId['menu1-1-1']],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('menu1-1-1'),
    name: 'menu1-1-1',
    ...
  }
]
```

Now I use populte to query the data.

```
this.menuModel.findOne({_id:ObjectId('menu1')}).polulate('childrens');
```

It returns:

```
{
  "_id": "menu1",
  "name": "menu1",
  ...,
  "childrens":[
    {
      "_id": "menu1-1",
      "name": "menu1-1",
      ...
      "childrens":["menu-1-1"]
    }
  ]
}
```

the `childrens` in `menu1-1` is not a `Menu` model list, just an `ObjectId` list, so why? The `populate` method cannot build a tree structure? If not, can I create a query so that it returns a tree? I have tried `aggregate` with the `$graphLookup` method, but it seems that it doesn't work either.

Comment: GraphLookup will not give the exact tree structure. It will give something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/m8nNRbLsWBB

Comment: hmm, GraphLookup doesn't work here.

Comment: I don't think any query can give you the exact nested structure. You'll have to work with some sort of variation

Comment: maybe the only way is recursiving the data.

Comment: yeah, single query can't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can `populate` nested data to the depth you want and achieve the desired result like so:

```js
this.menuModel.findOne({_id:ObjectId('menu1')}).polulate({
   path: 'childrens'
   populate: { // Populate the populated documents 
      path: 'childrens' 
   }
});
```